# Visual Studio Code, Conda, and Python Environments (I cannot get it working)

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, conda, environment

I am setting up Visual Studio Code on my pc and am running into difficulties with the python environment I created and Visual Studio Code.

However, when running some test code, I get an import error..

I installed Python 3.7.3 with miniconda to 'C:\Python37', and then created a clone of the base environment named 'sci' and installed some packages (numpy, pandas, matplotlib, scipy, scikit-learn) using cmd. I tested the install in cmd with commands as follows:

```
conda activate sci 
python
import numpy
print(numpy.array([1, 2, 3]))
```

and everything works fine.

I then installed Visual Studio Code (.zip, not with installer) to 'C:\VisualStudioCode', opened a folder for testing and used the 'Python: Select Interpreter' command to specify the sci environment I created above. Now when I run the following code I get an import error message:

```py
import numpy
numpy.array([1, 2, 3])

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Any idea why this is happening? The bottom left of my VS Code window states Python 3.7.3 64-bit ('sci': conda), but when typing `conda env list` into the VS Code terminal it still points to the base environment, so that might be a clue..

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: How are you running the code? By selecting "Run Python file In Terminal" from the CTRL-SHIFT-P menu?

Comment: Hi @darthbith, I got it working. I checked the PATH variable and found that when I add the path to my conda environment which I named sci to PATH, it works with Visual Studio Code. The paths I added to PATH are 'C:\Python37\envs\sci', 'C:\Python37\envs\sci\Library\bin', and 'C:\Python37\envs\sci\Scripts'.

Answer (score 4):

After much frustration trying to follow other solutions, this is what finally worked for me (on a Windows 10 machine) with Anaconda python installed.

- Open an Anaconda Prompt terminal.
- Choose the conda environment you want (e.g. `conda activate myenv1`)
- Finally type `code` from the command line to launch visual studio code.

When I do that and then open any python file and click 'Run Python File in Terminal' (triangle in top right of editor) and all runs well.

Comment: that's worked for me. did you find any other way to directly run vs code, not through conda?

Comment: same problem here

Comment: @PouyaSamie There is a manual solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56786224/how-to-fix-importerror-dll-load-failed-in-visual-studio-code-packages-instal).

Answer (score 0):

Add the conda environment to PATH.