# How to fix 'ImportError: DLL load failed' in Visual Studio Code (packages installed with Anaconda)

Tags: python-3.x, dll, visual-studio-code, anaconda, importerror

I have installed Anaconda (with the packages that come with it) and VS Code (from within the Anaconda Navigator). If I open VS Code from the Anaconda Navigator or from The Anaconda Prompt, every `import` works well.
But if I open VS Code directly, it throws an `ImportError`.

For example:

```
from PIL import Image
```

Gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\MyPrograms\Coding\Scripts\imageOperations.py", line 7, in 
    <module>
        from PIL import Image
    File "C:\MyPrograms\Coding\Software\Python\lib\site- 
    packages\PIL\Image.py", line 93, in <module>
        from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: That may be because opening VS Code with Anaconda might "load" it (specify VS Code) with all the packages that conda has, whereas only opening VS Code might need the packages in the folder of the project as it does not know where to get them from (not opened with anaconda).

Answer (score 5):

> 1. (type)               CTRL + SHIFT + P
> 2. (search for:)        open settings
> 3. (click:)             Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)

Then add three line configuration:

```
{
    ... # any other settings you have already added (remove this line)

    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["/K", "C:\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat C:\\Anaconda3"],
    "python.condaPath": "C:\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\conda.exe"
}
```

***Finally, Restart your VScode***

Comment: It worked but I expected more from VSCode.